# Capistrano rbenv not configured to use the proper ruby: 1.9.1 system ruby instead of 2.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rbenv

I am trying to fix one production server's deploy process that is currently failing due to using the wrong ruby being executed. The target ruby with `rbenv` is `2.2.3`. However, the Ubuntu 14 system on the server seems to be defaulting to `ruby 1.9.1`. I'm hoping someone on S.O. could perhaps pinpoint where the problem could possibly reside. Below is the full error:

```
Tasks: TOP => deploy:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as serv-deployer@server: cd '/var/local/fisbot/releases/20170707184851'; RAILS_ENV=production ./slave restart exit status: 1
cd '/var/local/fisbot/releases/20170707184851'; RAILS_ENV=production ./slave restart stdout: Nothing written
cd '/var/local/fisbot/releases/20170707184851'; RAILS_ENV=production ./slave restart stderr: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/local/fisbot/releases/20170707184851/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/local/fisbot/releases/20170707184851/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/local/fisbot/releases/20170707184851/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./slave:4:in `require_relative'
    from ./slave:4:in `<main>'
```

So from the documentation of rbenv [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Step 1: Checking to see if shims is in my path

```
printenv | grep PATH

PATH=/home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/shims:/home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
```

As can be seen from the above `PATH`, shims is correctly placed in the front of the path.

Step 2: Checking for `RBENV_VERSION`

```
rbenv shell

rbenv: no shell-specific version configured
```

So this is not applied here to my shell, but according to the documentation, if this fails, the next step will be executed so onwards.

Step 3: checking `.ruby-version`

When I execute both `rbenv local` and `rbenv global`, I can see that the output is `ruby 2.2.3`. Additionally, in my rails application on the target server, the `.ruby-version`'s contents contains `2.2.3`. So on those fronts I should be fine.

Step 4: Check `~/.rbenv/versions`

Looking in this directory reveals that I have `2.2.3`.

Step 5: I have executed `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`, Ran, ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init, and opened up a new window.

Finally for good measure, by executing `gem env` I can see that I am using `2.2.3`

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/serv-deployer/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /home/serv-deployer/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin
     - /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/serv-deployer/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /opt/puppetlabs/bin
```

Am I missing anything here? Everything indicates that I should be running the correct ruby so why is the command failing?

--------------EDIT------------

executing `rbenv versions` shows that I have two ruby versions

`system`
`2.2.3 (set by /var/local/fisbot/current/.ruby-version)`

As I should, is it recommended to purge the system ruby. If I can get rid of the system version then perhaps I can be set. I don't know if this is recommended though as this is a production system.

Comment: did you do -> `rbenv rehash` ?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer I just executed it now but to no avail. I didn't see any output or anything by executing the commnad. I tried a test deploy and the process still fails.

Comment: I just asked because I was once for quite a while trying to figure out why it wasn't loading correctly the local version I had just installed correctly and it was because I hadn't ran the rehash. It doesn't output anything.

Comment: 1. All of those commands were run on the server in `/var/local/fisbot/releases/20170707184851`?
2. I had a similar thing happen on a remote machine, and it was fixed by running `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` (which is now in my `.bash_profile` on that machine)

Comment: Have you added `gem 'capistrano-rbenv'` to your `Gemfile`? The [help](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv) is pretty straightforward to follow.

Comment: Yes, I have installed this gem which is why my issue is all the more puzzling. The capistrano deploy process is defaulting to the system ruby at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear from the question which commands you are running on your local machine and which you are running on the server. But I think the most likely scenario is that 1) your local machine has `rbenv` but 2) your server does not. In this scenario, your server doesn't have any idea what a `.ruby-version` file is and will need its system Ruby updated to match the `.ruby-version` that you use for development.

Comment: The commands are run on the server and rbenv is installed on the server. `capistrano/rbenv` is the gem being used to deploy to the server.